# What factors should be considered when setting budgets configuration in angular.json?

Tags: angular, progressive-web-apps, angularbuild, angular-config, angular.json

I am creating an Angular PWA that needs to be fast and light. When creating the angular application with the angular cli, I get a default budget that looks like this.

```
"budgets": [
  {
    "type": "initial",
    "maximumWarning": "500kb",
    "maximumError": "1mb"
  },
  {
    "type": "anyComponentStyle",
    "maximumWarning": "1kb",
    "maximumError": "2kb"
  }
]
```

Will these defaults be good for something like a PWA where users are on old tablets and expect the app to be fast and responsive? This is not a browsing app or something like that. It is for repeated transactions, like scanning items in a grocery store and doing business logic on each scan. Users can't be waiting a second after each scan or input action for a result or component to load. This will be global application where things like internet availability and speeds can vary greatly.

I have only just started development and have been using these defaults. I have not received any warnings about the budget so far, which concerns me that they may be too high for my purposes.

Comment: You misunderstand the meaning of the budgets. It is the size that is pushed to the client during *first-time access*. It has no impact on the wait after the scan.

Comment: the budget would mainly translate to initial load time.  It's not all that predictive of overall performance.  You'd need to do your own load/performance testing.

Comment: Budget configuration is size allocation to the application, for details check - https://angular.io/guide/build. It works like a household budget :)

Comment: Ok thank you! I see budget is not going to be helpful for this type of performance I am concerned about. 

I guess I thought this would include budgets for components or scripts so loading components doesn't take too long. I mentioned the scanning to get an idea of the app so I didn't get a bunch of "depends on your app" answers, but it is not to say that is the only moment I am concerned about.

Like @browsermator said, it looks like I have to do my own load testing to see how it performs with each component. I would still be interested in what people use for budgets in similar apps.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To answer your question - since many typescript applications use GRPC [GRPC Link](https://grpc.io/docs/guides/performance/) or similar technologies, one should think of the taxonomy of the available internet bandwidth on first load, installation time and network congestion. as an example in parts of east Africa the available network is 780kbs, so if one has a bandwidth intensive application - the data stream and package size is very important, keeping things local to the client is critical for a good user experience.

- **Application package size by Bandwidth availability**:

  56kbs - 380kbs frame maximum package 800kbs.

  384kbs-768kbs 4g/3g maximum package 2mbs storage reserve 1mb
  (caching)

  1.5mbs - 50mbs 4gLTE,3GS++ (AIRSPAN) maximum package 50mbs (browser max) storage reserve 10mbs-1GBS

  50MBS - 400mbs 5G maximum package 50mbs (browser max) storage reserve
  10mbs-1GBS

I worked in Africa I'm a software engineer, our mobile app had to be deployed in multiple countries with very poor cellular reception.

Modern Relay [React Relay Link](https://relay.dev)coupled with Angular worked very well.